# wordpress jquery animate scroll does not work in chrome and other webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, wordpress

My wordpress template file looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion"></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['kommune'])): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: (jQuery("#accordion").offset().top)
    }, 800);
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

jquery animate scroll does not work here. I dont know why. It works only in firefox. but no webkit and mobile browsers. I have tried to see if it gets the item's offset top, and it actually gets. May be there is a problem with the animate?? I am very unsure. I am using jquery version 1.11. I have used this code in many other projects(not wordpress), and it worked with no problem at all.

I have these style for body and html:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Can anything of these be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Cannot put height 100% to the HTML and Body. So I removed it from css and then it worked just fine. Don't really know why it did not work with this. 
Removed this from CSS:

```
height: 100%;
```

CSS look like this after:

```
html,body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: @Athimannil think you selected the wrong comment macro :) This is a possible answer, although not a very well explained / formatted one...

Comment: I do not have height: 100%; in my CSS and even though I have the same problem with webkit browsers and jQuery animate scrollTop: